# Access a variable of one function in another function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I declared a global variable in first function and I am trying to access that variable in my second function. But it's not working.
The variable name is `$unique_code`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'laksh_add_content_specific_email', 20, 4 );
function laksh_add_content_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    global $unique_code;
    $unique_code = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'laksh_add_content_specific_email2', 20, 4 );
function laksh_add_content_specific_email2( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
        echo '<h2 class="email-upsell-title">Redeem Code</h2>';
        echo '<p class="email-upsell-p"><strong>' . $unique_code . '</strong></p>';
        echo '<p class="email-upsell-p">Please show this code at the reception when you visit us to redeem your gift card.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to declare a global var outside the function like : global $var;

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Yes, that's not working either.

Comment: can you please explain what you need to do with that, may be there is a better way to do it somehow

Comment: Before Access global variable must use global keywords with variable name, like global $unique_code. And then you can use anywhere in the function.

Comment: PHP manual on [scope and global usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the variable outside of any function. Also use the global keyword in both functions. Further, ensure that `laksh_add_content_specific_email` is called before `laksh_add_content_specific_email2`.

```php
$unique_code = 0;

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'laksh_add_content_specific_email', 20, 4 );
function laksh_add_content_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    global $unique_code;
    $unique_code = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'laksh_add_content_specific_email2', 20, 4 );
function laksh_add_content_specific_email2( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    global $unique_code;

    if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
        echo '<h2 class="email-upsell-title">Redeem Code</h2>';
        echo '<p class="email-upsell-p"><strong>' . $unique_code . '</strong></p>';
        echo '<p class="email-upsell-p">Please show this code at the reception when you visit us to redeem your gift card.</p>';
    }
}
```